# jQuery hide all matching classes on click

Tags: jquery

**Scenario**

I'm in need of hiding all associated `classes` on `click` of the relevant button.

Then once there is only one `div` left I need to `disable` (or hide) that `button`.

So say if someone clicks `<button class="remove-box box-one">Remove</button>` it will hide all the elements that have `.box-one` only. This is similar for `.box-two` and `.box-three`.

NB: I can't change any of the mark-up.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box box-one">
    <button class="remove-box box-one">Remove</button>
</div>
<div class="box box-two">
    <button class="remove-box box-two">Remove</button>
</div>
<div class="box box-three">
    <button class="remove-box box-three">Remove</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 200px; height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
div.box-one {
    background: green;
}
div.box-two {
    background: yellow;
}
div.box-three {
    background: blue;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.remove-box').click(function () {
    var boxClass = $(this).attr('class');
    boxClass.each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    if ($('.remove-box') != null && < 2 ) {
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/jECX4/1/

Thankyou for your time.

UPDATE:

Thanks for the answers, I'll run through them before selecting the most appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: `if ($('.remove-box') != null && < 2 )`  What should be `<2` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff if there is only one `remove button` left, aka less than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jECX4/8/)

```
$('.remove-box').click(function () {
    var boxClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();
    $('.'+boxClass).hide();
    if ($('.remove-box:visible').length < 2 ) 
        $('.remove-box:visible').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: How would I only show the remove button if there were more than 2 elements? (and hide if 2 or less)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.remove-box').click(function () {
    var boxClass = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    var len = boxClass.length;    
    var cls = "";
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(boxClass[i].indexOf("box-") >= 0){
            cls = boxClass[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(cls != ""){
        $("."+cls).hide();
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/jECX4/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.parent()` to get the parent box.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fatgx/

```
$('.remove-box').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    if ($('.box:visible').length <= 1) {
        $('.remove-box').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here this one is working, http://jsfiddle.net/victorrseloy/wz5X3/

your js should be:

```
$('.remove-box').click(function () {
    //var element = $(this);
    var boxClass = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    $(boxClass).each(function () {
        if(this != "remove-box"){
            $("."+this).hide()
        }
    });
    if ($('.remove-box') != null && $('.remove-box').length< 2 ) {
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/SfJ8x/)</kbd>

```
$('.remove-box').click(function () {
    var boxClass = $(this).attr('class').match(/(box-.+)(?:\s|$)/g)[0];
    $('.'+boxClass).hide();
});
```

Comment: Hi, what does `.match(/(box-.+)(?:\s|$)/g)[0];` mean?

Comment: @Xareyo match any thing starting from `box-` till space or end.It returns array so we use `[0]` to access first value of array.

Comment: A regular expression is ab it too much for this purpose don't you think? It should be sufficient to check whether it contains box-

Comment: @Schnodderbalken RegExp is faster.

Comment: @TusharGupta RegExp is faster than what? Usually, RegExp is slower than anything else but anyway, this performance difference can be count in nano seconds regarding purpose here

Comment: @A.Wolff i thought less lines of code and it's faster but i don't know much coz i just learnt RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but surely you can just fadeOut the parent object when you click the "Removed" button?

http://jsfiddle.net/jECX4/12/

```
$('.remove-box').on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});

<div class="box box-one">
    <button class="remove-box box-one">Remove</button>
</div>
<div class="box box-two">
    <button class="remove-box box-two">Remove</button>
</div>
<div class="box box-three">
    <button class="remove-box box-three">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, potentially yes. I would need to get any also hide any future class that may match also.

Comment: Thanks for comment - I just saw @Hiral's answer which explained it all!